# Textarea Turning Iframe Tags into Special Characters

Tags: video

I am having an issue adding an iframe tag to a textarea field. The field is configured to accept XHTML. Any ideas on what could be causing the issue?

e.g.

```
&lt;iframe id="xtranormal_So, have you heard about Montana Conservation Corps?" name="xtranormal_So, have you heard about Montana Conservation Corps?"  src="http://www.xtranormal.com/xtraplayr/13045605/so-have-you-heard-about-montana-conservation-corps" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" border="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"&lt;/iframe>
```

I am running EE v2.5.0

Answer (score 1):

You should select "None" for "Default Text Formatting" under the field options.

It would work for you.

Comment: Also, make sure to apply this to existing entries if you want the current entry with the iframe tag to be updated too.

Comment: Yes, Ian is correct.